# How to backup a sharepoint site with guest access only

Tags: backup

I've tried for some time to find an effective way to store backup copies of sharepoint sites to which I have guest access only. I would like to store them on a NAS or similar, not relying only on my laptop. Below are 3 sub-optimal solutions, and a 4th which seems mostly suitable.

**Periodic manual download from website.** This is tedious and rather unreliable as download of large directories are prone to fail (in my experience). Files must thereafter be manually transferred to network storage.

**OneDrive app sync with 'Always keep on this device'.** This works, but can result in very high levels of actvity on the OneDrive app if you have many guest libraries, and the documents are frequently edited by other contributors. Files must be transferred to network storage manually, or using another backup tool such as Veeam Agent. Note that the Veeam agent for windows does not support backup of OneDrive files where the 'Files on Demand' option is enabled.

**Rclone.** This nifty tool allows for backing up OneDrive and Sharepoint sites directly to a NAS or similar. However for Sharepoint sites where you are only a guest-user do not show up in your sharepoint account, and a manual workaround via Microsoft graph is required.

Are there solutions out there to this dilema?

Answer (score 0):

The best I've come up with thus far (nspired by this work https://stephenreescarter.net/automatic-backups-for-wsl2/) is as follows:

'sync' any desired sharepoint site to my laptop via OneDrive app, and make use of the 'Files-on-demand' option.

Install Windows-Subsystem-for-Linux2 (WSL2) which makes it is possible to use Rsync on windows.

Rsync the folder to an external drive, NAS etc. Rsync will download each file in the directory, so you do end up with a local copy on your system, but critically it still avoids the hassles of utilising "Always keep on device" option. It's also possible to use the 'Free up space' option from OneDrive to clear the local copy if space is an issue.

This task can be readily automated using windows scheduler as CRON on WSL is a bit hit-and-miss (see Stephen Rees-Carters article linked above). Setting up ssh-keys will help if storing on a remote device.

The setup is local and no 3rd party services are required is nice